# Working with Devise Login / Session Validation Error Messages in Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, session, authentication, devise

This is my first stack overflow post so I apologize in advance if i ask the question poorly or leave anything out that could help answer the question. But please let me know if any other information would help and i'll respond right away!

Also, i'm working with a front-end css library called Semantic so i apologize for any clunkiness you might see in the erb files!

**The issue**: I am trying to validate the user login process and the errors are not showing for missing email and password fields. (**app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb**)

---

**What's strange**: I have studied many other stack overflow articles and other blogs and successfully displayed validation errors for the registration process (**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**)

---

**What I've done**:

1. require the validations in the User model:

`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :courses
  has_many :completions
  has_many :htmls, through: :completions

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true
  validates :goal, presence: true, length: { in: 10..100 }
end
```

`

2. modified my config/locales/en.yml file to include the following:

'

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            first_name:
              blank: "Your First Name is Required"
            last_name:
              blank: "Your Last Name is Required"
            email:
              blank: "Please enter an email address"
              taken: "That email is already taken"
              invalid: "Please enter a valid email address"
            password:
              blank: "Please Specify a Password"
              too_short: "Password must be at least %{count} characters long"
            country:
              blank: "Please Select Your Country of Residence"
            gender:
              blank: "Please Select Your Gender"
            goal:
              blank: "Please describe a goal you would like to achieve"
              too_long: "Your goal must be shorter than %{count} characters long"
              too_short: "Your goal must be longer than %{count} characters long"
```

'

3. write my **app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb** file

```html
    <h1><span class="hashtag">#</span> log in</h1>

        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { class: "ui form" }) do |f| %>

            <div class="field">
              <%= f.input :email, autofocus: true %>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
              <%= f.input :password %>
            </div>

              <div class="registration_buttons">
                <%= link_to 'register', new_user_registration_path, { class: "ui left floated huge register button" }%>
                <%= link_to "forgot password", new_password_path(resource_name), class: "ui left floated huge register button" %><br />
                <%= f.button :submit, "log in", class: "ui right floated huge login button" %>
              </div>

         <% end %>
```

4. The view page above for devise/sessions/new does not display the messages i customized in config/locales/en.yml, but here is **app/views/devise/registrations/new/html.erb** that's pretty much identical to the previous snippet and displays the messages correctly.

```html
      <h1><span class="hashtag">#</span> welcome to the community</h1> 

      <%= simple_form_for( resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path, html: { class: 'ui registration form' }) do |f| %>

        <div class="two fields">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.input :first_name, autofocus: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.input :last_name %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="two fields">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.input :email%>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.input :password%>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="two fields">
          <div class="field">
            <%= render "countries_dropdown" %>
            <div class="error"><%= @user.errors[:country][0] %></div>
           </div>
           <div class="field">
             <%= render "gender_dropdown" %>
               <div class="error"><%= @user.errors[:gender][0] %></div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.input :goal, wrapper_html: { id: "goal_input" },
            label_html: { id: "varchar_count" },
            input_html: { id: "goal_input_field" } %>
        </div>

        <div class="registration_buttons">
          <%= f.button :submit, "register", class: "huge ui right floated register button" %>
          <%= link_to "log in", new_session_path(resource), { class: "ui huge login button" } %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
```

5. I also created my own registrations controller that inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController:

'

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
  #prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  #prepend_before_action :set_minimum_password_length, only: [:new, :edit]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message! :notice, :destroyed
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
    resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
      resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
      previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
  end

  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
  end

  # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
  # temporary session data to the newly created user.
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
  # in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource)
    router_name = Devise.mappings[scope].router_name
    context = router_name ? send(router_name) : self
    context.respond_to?(:root_path) ? context.root_path : "/"
  end

  # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  end

  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", force: true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :country, :gender, :goal)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :current_password, :password, :country, :gender, :goal)
  end

  def translation_scope
    'devise.registrations'
  end
  #def update_resource(resource, params)
    #resource.update_without_password(params)
  #end
end
```

'

6. As a result, i've changed the routes file to include:

'

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
        root 'users#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated do
        root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
end
```

'

7. And here is my rake routes:
   [My Rake Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRuDC.png)
8. And here is my **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** upon request!

'

```
    1 <html>
    2   <head>
~   3     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'KodoTechnologies' %></title>
    4     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    5
    6     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all" %>
    7     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
    8   </head>
    9
   10   <body>
~  11
+  12     <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
+  13       <div id="admin_menubar">
+  14         <%= render "customs/admin_menubar" %>
+  15       </div>
+  16     <% end %>
+  17
+  18     <% if current_user && !current_user.admin? %>
+  19       <div id="student_menubar">
+  20         <%= render "customs/student_menubar" %>
+  21       </div>
+  22     <% end %>
+  23
+  24     <div id="content">
+  25       <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
+  26     </div>
+  27
   28   </body>
+  29
+  30   <%= content_for(:page_scripts) %>
+  31
   32 </html>
```

'

---

**Summary**:

1. As i mentioned before, the same error displaying method that works for the registration process does not work for the login process
2. I feel like my limit comes from my limited understanding of how the Devise SessionsController works under the hood. I've created my own RegistrationsController that inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController and had moderate success but I have no idea how to use the SessionsController and therefore couldnt debug or even implement my own validation process for sessions#create with flash error messages

---

**Question:**

Can anyone tell me what i might be doing wrong that's allowing validation messages being shown in the registration but not in the log in forms?

Let me know if i've left anything out, i'd love to provide everything you guys need. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file too? The Devise help advises using that for flash messages - I'm wondering if there's an issue there.

Comment: Hello ArtOfCode! i just went and added it as the 8th item on the list. I'm not sure how helpful it would be because it yields to other layouts (nested layouts) and there's a whole bunch of partials and yielding from there as well.

The thing is, i would totally use flash messages if i knew where the validations were actually taking place :( 

I dont think i understand the Devise SessionsController enough to know where i need to write the appropriate code for the custom validations and flash messages to be stored :o Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Devise help recommends that you include flash messages in your application layout file. Yours doesn't appear to have these; try including them. This will enable flash messages across the application, regardless of what route is being hit.

For a basic Rails project, you might use something like this:

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:alert].present? %>
  <p><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
```

If you're using Bootstrap with Glyphicons, I find the following template works quite well:

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
    <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:alert].present? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
    <%= flash[:alert] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hello ArtOfCode, OP here, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I had some other questions that popped up but i think your answer was a great place for me to start and i figured most of them out, thank you very much!

Comment: It would be great if you or anyone else who might read this thread could elaborate on how i might be able to customize these messages, or ultimately, how to get access to the part of the code where the username/password comparisons are being made within devise so i can create custom flash session variables containing very specific flash messages. I think this could be helpful for unique inline validation error message displaying and a couple other situations. If anyone can help me understand the highlighted process above, i'd love to accept that as the answer, thanks again ArtOfCode!